# Keep getting incomprehensible error in this very simple cython program

Tags: python, cython

Here's my very simple cython program.

**`test/__init__.py` (Blank file)**

**`test/__main__.py` (Main file)**

```
from test.program import Program
Program.Main([])
```

**`test/program.pyx`**

```
from .example import *
from .example cimport *

class Program:
    @staticmethod
    def Main(args):
        h = ExampleClass()
        h.SayHi()
```

**`test/example.pyx`**

```
cdef class ExampleClass:
    cdef SayHi(self):
        print("HI")
```

**`test/example.pxd`**

```
cdef class ExampleClass:
    cdef SayHi(self)
```

If I run this program by `py36 test/__main__.py`, program outputs this incomprehensible error..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test\__main__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from test.program import Program
  File "test\program.pyx", line 1, in init test.program
    from .example import *
TypeError: Cannot overwrite C type ExampleClass
```

If I modify the code

```
from .example import *
from .example cimport *
```

to one of following code blocks

```
from .example import ExampleClass
from .example cimport *
```

or

```
from .example import *
from .example cimport ExampleClass
```

or

```
from .example import ExampleClass
from .example cimport ExampleClass
```

, the error disappears and program runs nicely without error.

I can't really understand why original unmodified code outputs weird `TypeError: Cannot overwrite C Type ExampleClass`..
Can someone please help me to understand the error and what the problem is?

Comment: Some old mailing list discussion - may be an issue with re-declaring the `cdef` parts of the class - https://www.mail-archive.com/cython-dev@codespeak.net/msg06133.html

Comment: You probably want to avoid "import *" anyway as it's ambiguous.

Comment: @chrisb Thanks. I'm not sure what `cdef` parts in my code is redeclared..

Comment: @ngoldbaum That's true. I have to avoid that pattern.. but I'm just curious why above code not works

Answer (score 1):

In `program.pyx`, both the Python module and Cython imports are used.

When the `example.pyx` code is compiled, `ExampleClass` has already been defined as a native type.

The python level import then instructs the python interpreter to load the python module containing `ExampleClass` native type - note, not the Cython definition of it but the runtime python module.

As that type had already been declared at compile time by Cython with [a fixed definition](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/extension_types.html#attributes), it is seen as an attempt to re-declare a native type. That is what `TypeError: Cannot overwrite C type ExampleClass` means.

In other words, the python level import is trying to re-declared a statically defined C extension class which is not allowed by Cython.

In short, remove `from .example import <..>` lines from `.pyx` files.

Python level imports are only needed when there are both Python only, as in a regular `.py` file, and Cython only declarations that both need to be used - that is not the case above.

As a side note, relative imports are not supported by Cython's `cimport` and also best not to use `*` for imports. The relative `cimport` code will break when installed as a package.